# Will a T2D VM be ~twice as fast as N2D for the same price?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been looking over the new GCP price lists and I'm somewhat confused about the T2D VMs. The documentation states that these are running with hyperthreading disabled, at one physical core per vCPU. However, pricing per vCPU stays the same, which would make more sense if you were getting half the threads.

So is the following correct?

```
N2D 4 vCPU: 2 cores+HT for ~118€/mo (n2d-standard-4)
T2D 4 vCPU: 4 plain cores for ~118€/mo (t2d-standard-4)
```

If so, that should be a nearly 2x speed boost for scalable compute workloads.

Comment: The question is about performance, but when considering N2D vs T2D please remember about [T2D limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#t2d_limitations), such as lack of sustained use discounts, custom VMs or local SSDs.

Answer (score 3):

Testing this with two 4 vCPU/16 GB instances in Geekbench:

- N2D: [2247 multithreaded](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/18948893)
- T2D: [4424 multithreaded](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/18948763)

So it looks like, yes, you do get the same amount of full cores on T2D that you get threads on N2D for the same base price, and single core performance is similar at least in this superficial benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

In a [Redis Enterprise T2D benchmark](https://redis.com/blog/redis-enterprise-google-cloud-t2d-benchmarks/) made in Nov 2022 by Redis Ltd. in the single VM 16-vCPU throughput comparison, the T2D (always Milan) beats N2D Milan machines by about 50% and previous generation N2D Rome by about 75%.

Please note that while Redis is a single-threaded application, *Redis Enterprise* uses multiple Redis processes/shards so this should be treated as a multi-threaded workload test.

Comment: Note the `memtier_benchmark` you linked to is multi-threaded. The n2d and t2d instances have identical performance in single-threaded scenarios (e.g.: https://blogs.perl.org/users/dimitrios_kechagias/2022/03/cloud-provider-performance-comparison-gcp-aws-azure-perl.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read that it should have the same (or sometimes lower) perf for single-threaded workloads, that's why I am surprised with this benchark's result. But note that the benchmark has a single-threaded server, which is tested here. Only the client of `memtier_benchmark` is multi-threaded. Please correct me if I am wrong. PS Thanks for the link to the blog post, very interesting!

Comment: The benchmark uses multiple client threads to generate load, so it's a multi-threaded benchmark, which is why you see the difference. Anything actually single-thread I try on n2d vs t2d runs pretty much the same.

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't matter here if the client side of the benchmark is single- or multi-threaded. It's just generating the load and what was tested there was ...actually a multi-threaded Redis Enterprise, because it not the same thing as plain Redis. I updated my answer then. Thanks for digging deeper, @Ecuador!

Answer (score 1):

So, firstly, T2D cores are always Milan, for N2D you have to remember to specify the architecture, otherwise you get the much slower Rome cores.

For each vCPU on N2D you get a thread, where each core has 2 threads. For T2D you get a whole core per vCPU as HT is disabled. For single-threaded loads, their speed will be identical, for multi-threaded it depends on the specific workload, but you can get up to something like 70% more performance on T2D.

T2D is currently at a 25% price premium over N2D for on-demand instances, but the price is indeed the same for 1y/3y committed or spot instances. So you get more for the same price currently - just check as prices change.

Edit: I finished the write-up on some extensive benchmarking and price comparison on all instance types (and across providers), you can [check it out here](https://dev.to/dkechag/cloud-vm-performance-value-comparison-2023-perl-more-1kpp) ;)

Comment: "T2D is currently at a 25% price premium over N2D for on-demand instances" - that's not true, at least not in the few regions I am interested in, for example us-central1. There, as of now, the regular instance price of T2D is THE SAME as N2D for on-demand. However, as T2D does not support sustained use discounts, if these discounts apply to you the effective price for T2D will be higher.

Comment: For the spot instances, as of now, the price difference between N2D varies a lot between the regions, from just ~5% (us-central1) to ~25% more (us-east4) for T2D. But as these prices change even every 30 days, you should check them at the time you are reading it before making decisions.

Comment: Oh, I definitely factor in sustained use discounts when calculating prices - I either use spot instances, or sustained use ones. GCP pricing does vary a lot and at times it does not make much sense ;)